# Testrpc - How to turnoff writing messages to the console?

Tags: testrpc

Is there any way to force testrpc to stop writing messages to the console ?
Currently I am getting ton of messages  about getBlockByNumber

```
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_getBlockByNumber
net_version
```

The most important thing I need in the moment is list of accounts ( public and private key ) and after some time it is lost. The only solution I have is to write output to the file.`(testrpc > output.txt)` This works, but would be easier if I can just force testrpc to stop writing useless messages to the console.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems there's no flag to disable logging. But it should be a nice feature to have. I'd suggest to report it to the https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli it appears to be easy to implement.